# node-oracledb modifies output of a selected timestamp

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle-sqldeveloper, node-oracledb

when i use this the command inside oracle´s sqldeveloper:

`SELECT systimestamp FROM dual;`

i get an output in this format:

09-DEC-22 12.36.55.179000000 AM -03:00

but when i use the same command with node-oracle-db i get the output in this format:

2022-12-09T04:17:23.545Z

And i would like to get the same kind of output i get  using sqldeveloper

this is my code:

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb')


const dbCredentials = {
    user: "user",
    password: "password",
    connectString: "localhost:1521/xe",
  };

  async function timeget(dbConfig) {
    let connection;
    try {
      connection = await oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig);
      const result = await connection.execute
      (
        `SELECT systimestamp FROM dual`,
      )
    
      console.log(result.rows)
      connection.commit();
      return res1
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } finally {
      if (connection) {
        try {
          await connection.close();
        } catch (err) {
          console.error(err);
        }
      }
    }
  }

timeget(dbcredentials);
```

Comment: Since you are getting a Date object back, you can use Node.js functions and modules to do the formatting.  There are various StackOverflow answers showing how to format Dates.

Answer (score 0):

Change the SQL statement in your node.js code to output the timestamp as a formatted string:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         SYSTIMESTAMP,
         'DD-MON-RR HH12.MI.SS.FF9 AM TZH:TZM',
         'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English'
       ) AS formatted_timestamp
FROM   DUAL
```

Alternatively, read the [Node.js documentation on date handling](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/main/doc/api.md#datehandling) and fetch the timestamp as a string.

The documentation states (I have not tested it) that you can set this before opening the connection:

```nodejs
oracledb.fetchAsString = [ oracledb.DATE ];
```

to fetch all dates as strings or set the fetch info within the query:

```nodejs
const result = await connection.execute(
  'SELECT systimestamp AS time FROM dual',
  [],
  {fetchInfo: {'TIME': {type: oracledb.STRING}}}
)
```

Comment: The `fetchAsString` solution will fetch SYSTIMESTAMP as a string like `'12-DEC-22 08.12.55.054851 PM +11:00'`